# submit, redirect 301, потеря данных

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, submit

Здравствуйте.

На сайте, в htaccess висит redirect 301 (сеошники потребовали все адреса принудительно закрывать '/'). При отправке данных с формы (POST) стали теряться данные.

Подскажите, как победить эту проблему?

P.S. Подозреваю, что все дело в сессии, при редиректе её данные теряются, но как быть?

`session_start` и `session_name` вызываются.

[[@yarnik](/users/305/yarnik)](/users/305/yarnik)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-dRewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$RewriteRule (.+) $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: покажи правило которым ты закрываешь

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить проверку на метод отправки данных:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST$`

Или изменить коды формы так, чтобы запрос сразу шёл на верный адрес.